# I deploy an app develop with python and django on heroku. pgadmin. The deployment is successful but I have the logs --tail error when I launch it

Tags: python, heroku, pgadmin

[How do I deal to use my app on the platform heroku ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf9h8.png)

Comment: Post the logs code instead of images. I see you used \ instead of / in staticfile dirs.

Also provide additional details.

Comment: Also, that's your _deploy_ log showing a successful deployment. It doesn't tell us anything about the error you're seeing now. As the message says, please check your runtime logs by running `heroku logs`.